C# HttpClient timeout in web application
The code below works great in a console application.
When it runs on IIS in a web application it times out on the client.GetAsync(URL) line.
Any ideas?
       static async Task<byte[]> GetLogo(string URL, string AccessToken)
   {
       byte[] imageData = null;

       using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new   AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               imageData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

           }

       }

       return imageData;
   }

EDIT:
Just to make things a bit more crazy I used the older Service.Net.WebClient and it worked like a charm. In both console and web application.
This works:
        private MemoryStream GetStreamFromUrl(string url,string AccessToken)
    {

        byte[] imageData = null;
        MemoryStream ms;

        ms = null;

        try
        {
            using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                imageData = wc.DownloadData(url);
            }
            ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something
        }

        return ms;

    }

Thanks,

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) - you are using HttpClient wrong ... and still using it wrong ...

@Fildor Thanks for the suggestion but making that change did not solve the problem.

^^ But there may also be different issues. Do logs indicate something fishy? Windows Event Logs, maybe?

Are we talking about the same machine your console app and IIS is running on?

@Ralf Yes. Same machine. Same code.

@Fildor Nothing in logs that I've found so far.

Just to be sure here, could you add the exception details to the question? Do you perhaps have a firewall blocking your IIS service? Does this happen with any URL?

@Xerillio Currently just a Time out. I'll see if I can capture more detail. It works with any URL in the console. Fails with any URL in the web application.

But "just a time out" is not a thing in C# - that would be in the form of an exception, unless you've identified it differently. In that case it would be nice to know what you mean by that.

@Xerillio The browser just displays a Time out error message. It doesn't even get caught in the try/catch. I'm working on getting this going. https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/

Wait, how do you know client.GetAync(URL) is the issue then? This sounds more like your browser isn't even able to connect to your IIS site.

@Xerillio  Debugging has it timeout on that line. When pasting the URL into a browser I'm able to connect and the image downloads. Also remember the same code works fine in the console app.

The BaseAddress should be set for the HttpClient. Calling GetAsync should contain only resource part in the argument. Can you check this first. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient#http-get

It depends on the URL you are trying to access. If you are trying to access a url that is being served by IIS, then you cant access the fully qualified url without adding the URL to the local host file and set the IP to 192.162.0.1
Also, you are using should be injecting the HttpClient in the constructor, something like:
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
public Service(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

then in your method use something like, which is using async:
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var imageData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle unsuccessful response
                }
            }
        }


Search for "Event Viewer" in Windows, then navigate to the Windows Logs folder, and finally open the Application section. In this page, you can view the logs of IIS errors.
You can also log errors through the Web.config file.
Below, I'm providing you with a sample Web.config file. Note that this Web.config file is based on .NET 8 Also, you need to replace 'YourAppName' with the name of your application.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YourAppName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

Also, please note that the "\logs\stdout" folders should exist alongside the Web.Config file, and proper access should be granted to them.

I suspect you have some code further up your call stack that is calling .Result or .Wait() or similar on the task returned from GetLogo.
In an ASP.NET (pre-Core) application, that will deadlock, as explained on my blog. It does not deadlock if you do the same thing in a Console application (or ASP.NET Core application).
The proper solution is to remove the blocking code: change from .Wait() / .Result / whatever to use await instead.
